# Fatal error in Joomla components

Tags: joomla

I am very new to Joomla and I started with a tutorial in creating a database and creating a componenet. I have created a folder named com_joomlabook. Within that folder are 2 files.

joomlabook.php:

```
<?php

defined( '_JEXEC' ) or die( 'Restricted access' );
require_once (JApplicationHelper::getPath('joomlabook_html'));

$document=&JFactory::getDocument();
$document->setTitle('Example component Joomla! book');//set the page title 

switch(JRequest::getCmd('task'))
{          
    case 'free':
      // more display possibilities
       break;
    default:
       JoomlabookController::listJoomlabook();
       break;
}


class JoomlabookController
{
   function listJoomlaBook()
   {
      $db =& JFactory::getDBO();
      $db->setQuery('SELECT * from #_joomla_book');
      $rows = $db->loadObjectList();//get the results from the table
      Joomlabookdetails::view($rows);

   }
}
```

I have the file in the same directory as joomlabook.html.php. In this file I have the Class containing the method to view the results that I have retrieved from the joomlabook.php file.

Such as:

```
  <?php
  defined( '_JEXEC' ) or die( 'Restricted access' );


  class Joomlabookdetails
  {
    function view($rows)
    {
       foreach ($rows as $row) 
       {
         echo $row->text;
       }
    }
  }
```

But when i run it in the browser using:

```
http://localhost/joomla/Joomla_1.5.7-Stable-Full_Package/administrator/index.php?option=com_joomlabook
```

I get the error:

```
Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required '' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') 
in /home/ntdg/public_html/joomla/Joomla_1.5.7-Stable-Full_Package/administrator/components/com_joomlabook/joomlabook.php 
on line 6
```

This occurs on the getPath() call. Can anybody tell me why?

Answer (score 0):

You just have to pass 'html' to `JApplicationHelper::getPath`, example:

```
JApplicationHelper::getPath('html')
```

For reference you can look here: [JApplicationHelper::getPath](http://api.joomla.org/__filesource/fsource_Joomla-Framework_Application_joomlaapplicationhelper.php.html#a106)

Answer (score -1):

**JApplicationHelper is now deprecated in J3.0**

```
require_once(JApplicationHelper::getPath('admin_html'));
```

Seems to work with:

**for administrator**

```
require_once(JPATH_COMPONENT.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'admin'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'admin.html.php');
```

**for frontend**

```
      require_once(JPATH_COMPONENT.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'admin.html.php');
```

rename your file admin.componentname.php to componentname.php

above steps make non MVC components to run in J3.x